# npm package mime-types not working (giving undefined) with typescript (or nestjs)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, node-modules, mime-types

I am trying to use [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) in NestJs as follows.

```js
import mime from 'mime-types';

mime.contentType(req.url)
```

But mime gives me undefined even though I have installed mime-types npm package. It doesn't give any error in the editor (vs code)

Not facing any such issue with other packages. What is the issue with mime-types or am I using it incorrectly (On the official document also they have given CommonJs example not es6 example)

I checked in the simple node js file, there it is working. the issue only facing in NestJs (or Typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `import * as mime from 'mime-types'` instead. Or use [`allowSyntheticDefaultImports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports)

btw this due to how TypeScript works, NestJS has no opinions on how nodejs modules are loaded.

Comment: ok. * thing is working. But my allowSyntheticDefaultImports was true. still it wasn't working. any guess on that? I am using many packages with allowSyntheticDefaultImports

Comment: try it with `esModuleInterop`

Answer (score 0):

as of 2024 and mime @ 4, I changed (in package.json):

```
"type": "module",
```

and use:

```
import mime from 'mime';
```